# Docker Tomcat logging to catalina.out and to console

Tags: docker, tomcat

Docker tomcat container saves the startup log of the tomcat application in catalina.out file (last line would `INFO: Server startup in 136607 ms`). But rest of the activity of the tomcat app is logged onto to console and can be viewed with `docker logs container_id`.

Is there a way to log to file and console as well? I need the activity log inside catalina.out.2021.log in the tomcat container so I can run a script that collects analyze the logs and process it and sends email and It needs to run inside the container.

Tomcat is started with custom logging properties file `/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties` but the output is ending up on console and not in file.

Comment: Which docker image are you using?

Comment: docker.io/hobsonspipe/centos-tomcat7:latest That's the image I'm using

Comment: Also its in a kubernetes cluster.

Answer (score 1):

In the image you are using (`hobsonspipe/centos-tomcat7:latest`) the server is started with:

```
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/etc/tomcat/logging.properties
```

So you need to modify the `/etc/tomcat/logging.properties` file instead of the one used in your question. This file already does what you want: it sends all Tomcat logs to the standard output and `/var/log/catalina.<date>.log`, except log messages from the applications (if they use the `SevletContext#log` method) which go to `/var/log/localhost.<date>.log`.

If your application doesn't use neither `ServletContext#log` or `java.util.logging`, you must configure the specific logging framework elsewhere.

Comment: Any idea what all I need to modify or add?

Comment: I've tried log4j config but it is being ignored by tomcat image

Comment: @John: I added some details on the logging configuration in the answer.